# My table does not sorted by clicking the th tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

when i click on the "total_price" th tag the table dont sorted, but when i click on the "created_at" th tag the table sorted.
i have three components that communicate with each other.
i think the problems comes from "handleSortData" function in app.jsx (?)
maybe i should use usecallback ?

//app.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Table } from "./components/Table";
import { ordersService } from "./services/ordersService";

function App() {

  const [orders, setOrders] = useState(null);
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const ordersData = await ordersService.query(sortBy);
      setOrders(ordersData);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [orders, sortBy]);

   const handleSortData = (sortParam) => {
     console.log(sortParam);
     setSortBy(sortParam);
     const ordersData = await ordersService.query(sortParam);
     setOrders(ordersData);
   };
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {orders ? (
        <Table orders={orders} handleSortData={handleSortData} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

//Table.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function Table({ orders, handleSortData }) {
  

  const sortedData = (param) => {
    console.log(param);
    handleSortData(param)
  }

  return (
    <section className="main-table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={() => sortedData("order_ID")}>order_ID</th>
            <th onClick={() => sortedData("name")}>name</th>
            <th onClick={() => sortedData("total_refunded")}>total_refunded</th>
            <th onClick={() => sortedData("created_at")}>created_at</th>
            <th onClick={() => sortedData("total_price")}>total_price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {orders.map((order) => (
            <tr key={order.order_ID}>
              <td>{order.order_ID}</td>
              <td>{order.name}</td>
              <td>{order.total_refunded}</td>
              <td>{order.created_at}</td>
              <td>{order.total_price}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  );
}
```

//ordersService.js

```
export const ordersService = {
  query
}


function query(sortBy) {

  if (sortBy === 'total_price' || sortBy === 'order_ID') {
    return Promise.resolve(gOrders.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a[sortBy] - b[sortBy];
    }))
  } else if (sortBy === 'created_at') {
   return Promise.resolve(gOrders.sort(function (a, b) {
     return new Date(b[sortBy].date) - new Date(a[sortBy].date);
   }))
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(gOrders)
  }
}

const gOrders = [{...}]
```

Comment: does sort by `order_ID` work?

Comment: yes, but if i click on another th tag

Comment: the table gets sorted by `user_ID` if you click on a different `th` ?

Comment: i dont have a user_ID , im impliment only the th in ordersService.js (total_price, order_ID,created_at) for now.

Comment: the "created_at" dosnt sorted at all, maybe the logic is not properly,but i can overcome it later

Comment: i add  the last two lines in handleSortData function in app.jsx and its work!, but this is a good way to fix the problem?

Comment: Could it be cause of the value types maybe you need to cast them into numeric types. Check if you are storing the values as string and handling them as string.